# Can legendary dwellers line up out of vault if I'm at population cap?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I'm at 200 dwellers population, and running well.

I had just one lunchbox since, but I was wondering if I can still find legendary dwellers inside or they are excluded since I'm at max population?

Has anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, they can.

If you get a legendary dweller card, they'll come and line up outside, you just won't be able to let them in.

In order to let them in, remove a dead dweller, lowering your population to 199. As far as I'm aware, they'll wait indefinitely.

Comment: What happens if a raider attack happens, and there are dwellers outside?

Comment: They run off temporarily and come back when the emergency is over.

Comment: Note that you can only have 10 dwellers waiting outside your vault. If you already have 10 dwellers waiting outside your vault, you can't open lunchboxes.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I have some proof of that as well.
The dweller isn't legendary, but this proves that they can still be in lunchboxes.
[image]

[image]